# Problem with Hudson + Git + Gitosis on windows

Tags: git, ssh, hudson, gitosis

I have git and gitosis running smoothly on windows with msysgit (with OpenSSH),
and I would now like Hudson to start using git.

So, I have ensured that the hudson windows service is running as the 
hudson user, and I have added the hudson user through gitosis-admin.

I also have unixutils, and they are in the windows path.

But, Hudson fails at clone the project.

I can clone my project using git bash, when logged in as the hudson user,
but not on the windows command line,
and I am afraid this is how Hudson git plugin is attempting to do the clone.

When I try to clone from the regular command line, I get prompted for the git user's password.

I tried setting up a config file inside .ssh, but this didn't help.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get prompted for the git user's password

It should mean it doesn't find your public/private ssh key, most probably because, when Hudson runs a job, it has no `%HOME%` environment variable.
You should make sure a `%HOME%` is set under which a git process could find a `.ssh` directory

Comment: awesome! I was starting to tear my hear out on this one.