# Hudson Git Plugin not working on windows

Tags: git, ssh, hudson, msysgit, ssh-agent

I have msysgit installed with OpenSSH option. In Git bash, I can run ssh-agent, and it manages the passphrase for my ssh key. Is it possible for the Hudson Git plugin to use ssh-agent? Currently, it hangs when trying to clone, no doubt waiting for the passphrase to be entered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in ["Problem with Hudson + Git + Gitosis on windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182012/problem-with-hudson-git-gitosis-on-windows), you need to make sure the Hudson job does set first a `%HOME%` environment variable.
That value must refer to the directory where you can find:

```
.ssh
  id_rsa     # private key
  id_rsa.pub # public key
```

Comment: Thanks, VonC. I've set %HOME% as a user environment variable. Wouldn't it pick this up? Also, as an experiment, I generated a new ssh key with blank passphrase, and hudson is still hanging. If I run the hudson git command from the command line, it succeeds in cloning the repo.

Comment: @Jacko: it needs to be setup from the Hudson configuration settings to be extra sure. That would explain why Hudson jobs hang while command line Git commands pass.

Comment: Thanks you, sir!! I added a %HOME% parameter, http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build, and now it is cloning.

Thanks again!!!!!!

Comment: I cannot vote this answer up high enough.  After HOURS of messing around with it this was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this exact same problem but in my case setting `HOME` didn't fix it!

In my case the fix was actually to set the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables so it would seem that different Windows Git builds (mine is version `1.8.1.msysgit.1`) use different environment variables to locate SSH keys.

If in doubt, make sure you configure Hudson with all three!

Note also that you can configure Hudson-wide environment variables under 'Manage Hudson' > 'Configure System' > 'Global Properties', so you don't need to do this for each job individually.