# Jenkins hanging at "Fetching upstream changes from origin"

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins on a Windows Server 2012 machine, and I'm having a lot of difficulty.

Things I've done:

- Created a password-less `id_rsa`, and `id_rsa.pub`
- Created a `known_hosts` file for bitbucket.org using `ssh.exe -T bitbucket.org` and accepting to add the host.
- Added `E:` to System-wide HOME Variable
- I've added those files to `C:/Windows/SysWOW64/config/systemprofile/.ssh` as well as `E:/.ssh`
- I've linked my public key to Bitbucket as a deployment key.
- I've triple-checked all my URLs, usernames, etc.
- I've even manually pulled from the repository to setup an initial base in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/`

And yet it still hangs at

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyProject\workspace
Checkout:workspace / C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MyProject\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@13ca972
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
```

I've given it about 20 minutes, so it's not a speed / size of the repo issue. If I cancel, this is what is returned:

```
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files     (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch -t origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:780)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:739)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.fetch(CliGitAPIImpl.java:160)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:230)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:793)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$000(GitSCM.java:57)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:976)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1364)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:670)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:575)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Native Method)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:319)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:360)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:769)
... 19 more
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:981)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1364)
at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:670)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:575)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

I'm at my wits end here, so I appreciate all the help I can get.
Here are a choice few articles which I've tried with no improvement.

[Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)

[Permission denied (publickey) when setting up Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515039/jenkins-git-permission-denied-publickey)

[Hudson Git Plugin not working on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188710/hudson-git-plugin-not-working-on-windows/3188786#3188786)

http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/jenkins-git-clone-via-ssh-on-windows-7-x64

Comment: Is this a PATH issue? (http://blog.cgdecker.com/2011/02/git-clone-error-on-jenkinshudson-on.html)

Comment: Double check HOME from within a running instance of Jenkins (as in http://blog.hlyh.dk/2011/07/debugging-hudson-git-plugin-hanging.html)

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. The frustrating thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. So everything must be configured correctly, but it's just randomly failing.

Answer (score 31):

Here's how I fixed a similar issue:

Msysgit installs two `git.exe`. One under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` and a second one under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`. The first one cannot be used with Jenkins. It will hang after completing it's job. The second one works perfectly.

Update your Jenkins Git settings to point to the correct `cmd\git.exe` and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I solved it:

I ran the sysinternals tool psexec to spawn a CMD which is running under the LocalSystem account (same account like jenkins service is running)

```
PSEXEC -i -s -d CMD
```

In this cmd prompt I executed the same git command from the workspace directory as the hanging GIT.exe processes do. E.g.

d:\Programs\Jenkins\jobs\jobname\workspace>D:\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe fetch -t ssh+git://gitpub@my.server.com:9360/data/gitpub/myRepository.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Et voila: I was prompted to enter "yes" to add the SSH key to the known list of known hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Just experience the freeze at 'Fetching upstream changes from origin' as well.

Running Jenkins as a service on a Windows based machine seems to (from what I have experienced) to have issues when using SSL.

**Workaround Solution]**

1. Alter your Jenkins service to run under a local account.
2. Ensure your local administrator account is configured to perform Git interaction with SSH.
3. Restart Jenkins ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/jenkins-manual-restart)).
4. If Jenkins does not start, it had issues trying to pull from Git. Manually kill git and ssh processes, kill your java.exe from Jenkins and manually start the Jenkins service.

**Details on Why I Choose this Solution]**

I have followed other steps before with setting up the authorized host to accept the server and registering the Jenkins' key on the server to permit the connection. I've made sure I could successfully perform Git actions under my Local System account (which the Jenkins service was run under). Still, the fetch would freeze. To check that my Git and SSL was configured correctly, I even went to the initially configured Git repository in my Jenkins jobs directory and performed a successfully pull request [under the local system account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account). It worked; therefore the keys have been setup correctly.

I forgot where I read this, but I heard issues arise when dealing with Git/SSH under a local system. With this knowledge, I played with my Git environment and altered the GIT_SSH environment variable to use [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)  (with a combination of Putty to remember the server key, puttygen to convert an OpenSSL key to a Putty key and pageant to remember my keys) for plink. Once I got it working with plink, I did not find it to be a useable solution. I order to correctly use plink, I had to also run pageant under my local system account to have the Jenkins service correctly negotiate SSH calls. After thinking how I would correctly setup my initial state on reboot, I didn't want to put all this effort into just getting the SSH connection working.

Instead, I decided it was easier to just run Jenkins under my local administrator account which was also configured to deal with the Git server. No having to deal with configured SSH keys for the local system account and my git actions worked fine.

---

Note, David Gageot's answer can apply to some. I did not have to alter any of my Git settings as when I installed Git, I choose the option `Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt` which maps a path to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\cmd\` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Another link that I found very helpful when configuring jenkins on windows, especially when using the MSI installer is this: http://opensourcetester.co.uk/2013/06/28/jenkins-windows-ssh/

And one more thing that I didn't find obvious was: you have to use SSH url when connecting to Github instead of default https one. Hopefully that will save time to someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on my laptop and I was able to figure out a solution, however this really only applies if you are running the Jenkins war in a Tomcat web container that is setup as a Windows service.

I just had to set the Tomcat service to logon as my windows user instead of Local System.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the permissions on the $HOME/.ssh folder and its content. After setting it visible for the specific user group, Jenkins was able to fetch the changes after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

[Version 2.6.1 of the Git client for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads)  fixes this problem in Jenkins. Now “Fetching upstream changes from origin” has no delay.

I am using the git cmd in Jenkins from:

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 0):

I spent few hours trying to figure this out and I found out that adding the password to the repo URL fixed the issue:

```
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/REPO.git
```

Please note the **:** between username and password