# Can't authenticate with GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, jenkins

I'm trying to get my Jenkins server to authenticate with GitHub so I can build when changes are pushed. I've tried this  https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys a dozen times with no luck. Every time I try to fetch from Jenkins it times out after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating your ssh key from the Jenkins server? If so, are you able to `git clone` or `pull` manually from your Jenkins server?

**EDIT:**

Check out this *[link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin)* and see if this helps any:

**EDIT 2:**

If you're using windows and msysgit take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708490/jenkins-hanging-at-fetching-upstream-changes-from-origin)

Comment: I'm generating them from the machine my jenkins server is running on? And I don't know how to manually clone or pull from it.

Comment: Once you have generated your key from the jenkins server, added it to your github account, try to clone your repo on your jenkins server by `git clone [user]@github.com:[repo].git`

Comment: Yeah I can clone my repo. What do you mean on my jenkins server? I have the server running on this computer, and I can clone my repo into my home directory and such...

Comment: I edited my answer and added a link, see if that helps. Are you running jenkins from your computer where you can clone stuff into?

Comment: Yes, and I checked out the link. What bothers me is that my coworker got it working without using that plugin, and we both can't figure out why it won't work on my computer.

Comment: Are you using a Windows machine?