# Frequent ssh connection failure to github

Tags: git, github, ssh, jenkins

I am noticing my jenkins jobs failing frequently but not consistently. It might be an internal firewall issue but i wanted to check if anyone can point me to something that i haven't checked so far. The jenkins jobs, involves:
1. a git fetch &
2. a git tag

The jobs either fails at #1, if it succeeds in #1 it sometimes fails at #2 Else the job is successful.

The console log, when it fails on #1:

```
> git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:myorganization/myproject +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:myorganization/myproject
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:myorganization/myproject
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:627)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:865)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:890)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1259)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:myorganization/myproject +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And console output it fails @ #2

```
Updated data_bag_item[dev::dev]
tagging git for env dev
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error occured:
  AutoTagger::Git::Repo::GitCommandFailedError (AutoTagger::Git::Repo::GitCommandFailedError)
/opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/gems/auto_tagger-0.2.10/lib/auto_tagger/git/repo.rb:58:in `exec'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/gems/auto_tagger-0.2.10/lib/auto_tagger/git/ref_set.rb:36:in `fetch'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/gems/auto_tagger-0.2.10/lib/auto_tagger/base.rb:40:in `fetch'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/gems/auto_tagger-0.2.10/lib/auto_tagger/base.rb:33:in `create_ref'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/gems/auto_tagger-0.2.10/lib/auto_tagger/command_line.rb:49:in `execute'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/gems/auto_tagger-0.2.10/bin/autotag:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/bin/autotag:23:in `load'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/bin/autotag:23:in `<main>'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /opt/mount1/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@oss/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
```

.. 
I have 2 jenkins slaves with this issue, i build another jenkins slave and the 3rd also shows the similiar issue. Below are the things that i have verified:

1. The jenkins user, who performs the build job have the right RSA private key for the public key in the github account. I can do a ssh -T git@github.com just fine.

   [jenkins@slave3 ~]$ ssh -T git@github.com
   Hi myaccount! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
2. Below is the /home/jenkins/.ssh/config file

   Host github.com
     HostName github.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myprivate-key
     StrictHostKeyChecking no

i have tried to use port 443 for the ssh connection but my network doesn't seem to like it. Before i change the config file to use port 443, i test manually with the command

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@github.com
```

3. I have created a basic shell script and let it ran for every 10secs. It picked up ssh connection failures but not as frequently as i am encountering on the jenkins.

Note: please dont mark this as dup. i have looked up some of the connection issues to github like these:

[Jenkins: Failed to connect to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557998/jenkins-failed-to-connect-to-repository?rq=1)

[Can't authenticate with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643251/cant-authenticate-with-github?rq=1)

But they are not even remotely similiar

Comment: I just had another failure in  git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:myorganization/myproject +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*   .. So went into the jenkins slave, su to the jenkins user and tried the same command in the right workspace. It failed with "Connection timed out". But its surprising that the ssh connection test using "ssh -T git@github.com" worked. Is this now something else apart from the SSH connections?

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?